# Child theme not importing parent styles

Tags: child-theme, css

I have created a child theme for my parent theme. Just added `style.css` and `functions.php` files in child theme.

Original Theme Name: Verb Lite (Directory name verb-lite)

I created new folder `verb-lite-child` in themes folder, added the following files.

`style.css` file

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Verb Lite Child Theme
 Description:  A child theme of the Verb Lite theme
 Template:     verb-lite
 Version:      1.0.0
*/
```

`functions.php` file to enqueue parent styles,

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function theme_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . 
    '/style.css' );
    }
?>
```

Now when I preview my theme, the styles are broken, the parent styles are not loaded.

Is there anything I missed there.

Comment: Your `style.css` might have problem in its header. Try removing the `Theme` word from the name, and also try to include the full header as shown [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: @JackJohansson I tried to remove name and also included full header. But still the styles are broken.

Answer (score 1):

If I open syyle.css from original theme I see

`*/
/* Themely is based off of Understrap which uses the Underscores starter theme merged with the Bootstrap Framework. The default styles can be found in /css/theme.css and /css.theme.min.css.`

The styles loaded when I enqueued `theme.css` ad `theme.min.css` files.

My `functions.php` file now

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'verb-lite-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'verb-lite-cssstyles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'verb-lite-cssMinstyles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.min.css' );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is wrong `$handle` for the parent theme you use. Change `parent-style` to *Verb Lite's* `verb-lite-styles`.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'verb-lite-styles', // See here
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'
    );
}
```

> `parent-style` is the same `$handle` used in the parent theme when it registers its stylesheet

(Citation from [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Creating_a_Child_Theme_from_an_Unmodified_Parent_Theme))

### Updated

according the OP's self-answer.

*Verb Lite's* 'enqueue styles' is poorly programmed and doesn't use style dependencies, as could be seen in it's [`inc/enqueue.php`](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/verb-lite/1.1.6/inc/enqueue.php) file.

Enqueue all the styles with the respect of their dependencies:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'verb-lite-understrap-styles',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.min.css',
        array() // no dependencies
    );
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'verb-lite-google-fonts',
        'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i|Open+Sans:100,300,400,600,700,700italic,600italic,400italic'),
        array(
            'verb-lite-understrap-styles',  // depends on understrap
        )
    );
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'verb-lite-styles',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array(
            'verb-lite-understrap-styles', // depends on both understrap and Google fonts
            'verb-lite-google-fonts'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: See my answer, i could load styles, but the menu's custom css changes, and all  didn't come.

Comment: See the updated answer.